# Replacing backslash (\) in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem replacing backslash with text in JQuery. I have the following variable:

```
var a = [];
a[0] = 
"\
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\
X......................................X\
X.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.X\
X......................................X\
"
```

I'm using this code to replace the backslash, but It doesn't work.

```
<script>
a[0] = a[0].replace(/\\/g, "fsdf");
document.write(a[0]);
</script>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: That's because there are no backslashes in that string.

Comment: would you add commas? a[0].replace("/\\/g", "fsdf");

Comment: This is a multiline string it isn't considered as backslashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A backslash followed by a newline allows you to compose long strings on multiple lines without having to close and reopen the string enclosure; the resulting string is a concatenation (i.e. without newlines):

```
var a = 'hello\
world';
console.log(a);

> helloworld
```

If you want backslashes in the final string, just add them (and escape them too):

```
var a = 'hello\\\
world';
console.log(a);

> hello\world
```

Comment: Is there any way to replace backslashes with any other chars?

Comment: @racunalnik52 Updated answer to show how you would add backslashes.